# Register temp table in dataframe not working

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, temp-tables

Below is my script to use sql in dataframe with python:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('file:///root/Downloads/data/flight201601short.csv')
```

df.show(5) 
shows result below:

[image]

then I register the dataframe to a temp table:

```
df.registerTempTable("flight201601")
```

and tried to run some sql query like below:

```
sqlContext.sql("select distinct CARRIER from flight201601")
```

It doesn't produce expected result, instead:

[image]

I also tried:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from flight201601")
```

and it gives me:

[image]

So it seems the registerTempTable method only create the table schema and the table is NOT populated, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to call `show()` method on Dataframe returned by `sqlContext.sql` to get the result of query. Check the spark [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically) which says

> The sql function on a SQLContext enables applications to run SQL queries programmatically and returns the result as a DataFrame.

```
sqlDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from flight201601")
sqlDF.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

@PasLeChoix

when you are executing the below statement

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from flight201601")
df.show()
```

Spark will return the DataFrame. So you need to store your result into DataFrame and use the show() command to Display your result on to console as mentioned by @abaghel.

By Default, whenever Spark returns the DataFrame it will only show the schema on the console as you are getting in your case.